# Re-ordering / re-arranging twitter bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: reorder columns]

I need to reorder my columns like this, but since you can't do `col-sm-pull-12`/`col-sm-push-12`, I'm having trouble even getting close. Is there any possible way to do this with Bootstrap? If not with Bootstrap, how can I achieve something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/5d9y6kfc/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 red">
      A
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 blue">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 green">
      C
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 yellow">
      D
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 magenta">
      E
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show the HTML code you're using to create the image on the left.

Comment: Wp. The JSfiddle is blank.

Comment: are you allowed to use javascript and jquery?

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast yes, I could but I'm trying to avoid it if there's a native way in bootstrap. I essentially just need B and C to be swapped at the XS screen size.

Comment: use push and pull classes. Check them out. they are really good for ordering stuff.

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast Yes the problem is you can't do col-xs-pull-12, you can only push/pull a row at a time. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

so the reason you cant do this with bootstrap `push` and `pull` classes is because `push` and `pull` classes dont allow jumping of rows (if you push or pull beyond the set 12 columns of the grid system, it will off the screen)

an alternative is to use the `hidden` class of bootstrap. here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/282/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="a col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">Content of A</div>    
    <div class="b col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">Content of B</div>    
    <div class="c col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">Content of C</div>        
    <div class="c col-md-4 col-lg-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">Content of C</div>
    <div class="b col-md-4 col-lg-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">Content of B</div>
    <div class="d col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">Content of D</div>
    <div class="e col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Content of E</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: you are duplicating data... that is never a good way of doing but it works. I thought it this way too but I wouldn't advice anyone to do it.